# LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm trying to add the LLvm dev nightly branch to ubuntu trusty.
for the stable branch doing this is ok:

```
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Honestly I don't know how to do the same for the dev branch.
There is no

```
echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0 main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`. running this returns `404 Not Found
```

when I run `apt-get update`.

From the nightly build website, there is this for the dev builds:

```
wget -O - http://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add - 
# Fingerprint: 6084 F3CF 814B 57C1 CF12 EFD5 15CF 4D18 AF4F 7421`
```

So how can I add the dev builds to the apt list?
for reference here is the address for the nightly packaes:
http://apt.llvm.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLVM keeps a script that can be used to just do all the above for ubuntu/debian [here](https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh).

You can use that to do the task or you can study that to learn how to properly do it.